# Can I avoid Squating by doing sumo deadlifts

Tags: strength-training, squats, deadlifts, powerlifting

I dont like squating, so Im avoiding doing squats. However I enjoy deadlifting and Im doing them every day.  A different variation each day.
Is it really necessary to squat actually if you can do sumo instead? Or is there something special happening while doing the squat, something unique, that the deadlift doesnt give you?

Comment: What exactly are you working out for? Different exercises serve different purposes. Knowing your goals will help determine which exercise you should do.

Comment: My goal is to improve overall maximal strength and power. Deadlifting is one major part of my program due to that I m limited in time in the gym and want to gain the most of it. Thanks

Comment: While you can approximate it with multiple isolation lifts, keeping some form of squatting (even if it's not heavy) would be good for your mobility. It would even have a great carry-over to your deadlift. Have you tried most squatting variations?

Comment: Actually it´s the motion and the feeling on my back while doing the squat that I don´t like. I tried Zercher-Squats, but It doesn´t feel comfortable though. Maybe it is really something that you need to do to have a good balance of everything to do the squating (with a bar), do it and don´t think about it. Thanks for all the comments and thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squatting isolates the quadriceps and glutei. Strong thighs are useful if you're looking to achieve explosive power from the legs.

Deadlifting not only works out quadriceps and glutei, but also strengthens calves, hamstrings, abdominal muscles, and the trapezius.

I think it's a good balance to not only work out with deadlift but get individualized muscle groups in there. This will allow you to target areas of your body better, allowing for more vigorous workout without tiring your whole body.

Does this make sense?

Comment: This makes perfectly sense, and I m not doing deadlifts only I was just thinking if I can somewhow Substitute the benefits of the squats by doing a wide stance sumo-deadlift instead because it involved the legs more. My usuall training involves a deadlift variation, a Overhead pressing and switching from bent-over rows and benching each day. Thanks though